# Can Bus set bitrate error | RTNETLINK broken pipe

Tags: can-bus, socketcan

I am trying to set a can connection with one node.
I am using IXXAT USB to can adapter
http://www.netbiter.com/images/librariesprovider8/product-images/pc-can-interfaces/interfaces-usb-to-can-2-compact-subd.png?sfvrsn=2

and using the following socket can driver but gettin an error while setting the bitrate

"http://www.ixxat.com/support/file-and-documents-download/drivers/socketcan-driver

Below are the results from the commands that might help in getting the idea what's wrong.

> #### ip link show
>
> 1: lo: mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 
>   2: eth0: mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 link/ether 00:07:32:38:ab:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>   3: eth1: mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 link/ether 00:07:32:38:ab:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
>   5: can0: mtu 16 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 10
>
> #### xyz@abc:~/socketcan_1-1-92-0_20150508$ lsmod | grep can
>
> can_raw                20480  0 
>   can                        32768  1 can_raw
>   can_dev                20480  2 ixx_pci,ixx_usb
>
> ### dmesg
>
> [  592.860214] usb 1-1: Product: USB-to-CAN V2
>   [  592.860218] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: IXXAT
>   [  592.860222] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: HW442744
>   [  592.869494] ixx_usb 1-1:1.0 can0: attached to USB-to-CAN_V2 channel 0 (device HW442744)
>   [  742.106278] usb 1-1: sending command failure: -32
>   [  742.106366] ixx_usb 1-1:1.0 can0: couldn't set bitrate (err -32)
>   [  813.182948] usb 1-1: sending command failure: -32
>   [  813.183036] ixx_usb 1-1:1.0 can0: couldn't set bitrate (err -32)
>
> #### Setting bitrate
>
> Xyz@Abc:~/socketcan_1-1-92-0_20150508$ sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 1000000
>   RTNETLINK answers: Broken pipe

Any kind of inputs will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see any error on your side, but never used the IXXAT USB SocketCAN driver. Have you tried it with other bitrates, lower than 1000000?

Comment: please try

sudo ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000

the difference is setting "up" the network

Comment: Hello hjoe, thanks for the input I have been using the same commands to bring up the interface.But some times i have to pull ou the adapter from the PC and plug it again, then it works.Not sure about the reason.